# Search Results disapears after sorting, paging and refinering

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, sharepoint-on-prem

i have the following scenario:

I have a page with a searchresults webpart and a refiner webpart. 
The Search results webpart contains a filter paramter that use a parameter "k" from the query string.

So if I call the url http://machine/Pages/results.aspx?k=* it results me all the results. So far so good.

No I am on the results page and clicking on the refiners some times, and suddenly the results are gone and I could not get them back. This occurs on paging and sorting too.

Now the mysterious thing

Wenn i Add an "&" to the query string obove like: http://machine/Pages/results.aspx?k=*&

Then the sorting, paging and refinering (is that the right word?) works very well.

I can redproduce it on some machines but not on all. What can occur this problem?

IIS Setting? Do I use this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this on a Search Center site? or is it a custom site?
Also, are you using a custom masterpage? I had problems before with some jQuery/javascript that for some reason were breaking the search results webpart and after the user tried to search it was displaying nothing. In my case, I had to use ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded function for some javascripts to run after "sp.js" and other default SharePoint javacripts.

Check your custom jQuery/javascript to see if any of them are broken or something.
If you are using a custom masterpage, put seattle back and try to see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: Hi I use a custom Page, but this is an normale PageLaoyut Page without special javascript code or s.th.

Comment: So, you are using all of these by default (Masterpage and PageLayout)? this custom page, where did you create it? is it a Search Center Site?

Comment: Yes. I created used an existent one, after i modify the ASP.NET Markup I deploy this within a wsp Package.  In this wsp Solution I preconfigure the search results Webpart weithin the filenode in the Elements.XML. Nolting Special, only a normal deployment. Maybe the Problem is that I use the "k" Parameter in the request fort transmittingnthe searchtext?